# How to solve the log Equation

Tags: logarithms

I tried to solve the Equation but unfortunately Whatever I try, I can't solve the Equation

$$100^{\log x}=3x^3$$

Comment: I would recommend solving for $\log x$ after taking logs of both sides.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

$$100^{\log x}=3x^3$$
$$(10^2)^{\log x}=3x^3$$
$${(10^{\log x})}^2=3x^3$$
$$x^2=3x^3$$
$$3x^3-x^2=0$$
$$x^2(3x-1)=0$$
$$x=0,\frac{1}{3}$$

But, $x$ must be positive, so the only solution is $\frac{1}{3}$

Comment: With appropriate caveats, of course, about the "solution" $x = 0$.